# Use AngularJS Filters in Polymer Element

Tags: angularjs, polymer

Is there a way to use filters from the AngularJS library within a custom polymer element?

I'm trying to use AngularJS as a "framework" for my app with polymer to try out paper elements. I'd like to format currency but there's no built-in filter in Polymer but there is one in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`polymer-filters`](https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-filters) component, it provides a set of filters analogous to what you find in AngularJS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "Use the `polymer-filters` component" is the answer to "Is there a way to use filters from the AngularJS library withing a custom polymer element."

Comment: polymer-filters does not provide any number format filters, I added a feature request: https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-filters/issues/5
Also, what if I wanted to share custom filters between the Angular & Polymer? I'd like to be able to do that as well.